# Diff compression

Tags: code-challenge, compression

For this challenge, you need to compress a diff.  **A diff is some data that represents the difference between two strings.**  For this challenge, you need to provide one or more programs that can:

1. Input `A` and `B`, and output a diff, `C`
2. Input `A` and `C`, and output `B`
3. Input `B` and `C`, and output `A`

**The goal is to make the diff, `C`, as small as possible.**  The diff can be anything: a string, a number, a blob of data.  We just care about the size (number of bytes).

I have 50 test cases [that can found on Github](https://gist.github.com/nathanmerrill/125a6e2ae7d9ded3531fedff036cf74b).  Each test case consists of two space-separated URLs which point to the 2 files you need to diff.  (These test cases originated from PPCG members' Github profiles.  Thanks all!)

All three tasks above should take under a minute to run on a reasonably powered computer (for each test case).

Your score is equal to the total size (in bytes) of all 50 diffs, lower is better.   Hardcoding diffs in your program is not allowed (I reserve the right to change the test cases to prevent hardcoding). Builtins that produce a diff (like `diffutils`) are not allowed.

Comment: What precisely is a diff?

Comment: Anything you want it to be, really.  Informally, its a string that represents the differences between `A` and `B`

Comment: For tasks 2 and 3, do we have to dynamically figure out which which file is which, i.e., do we get the contents or the name of the file as input? Also, is built-in compression allowed?

Comment: @Dennis You can make 3 different functions/programs if you'd like, and assume that they each get the correct input (as a string or filename).  Built-in compression is allowed.

Comment: In other words, you can assume that 1,2,3 are completely independent tasks.

Comment: You explain what is a diff, but what is a string? Any sequence of bytes? Just printables? Can it contains null bytes?

Comment: @edc65 [a sequence of characters](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/whats-a-string).   You should be able to handle unprintables.  However, I don't care if you assume a certain encoding.

Comment: Can we assume all input is ASCII?

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix yes.

Comment: Hmm.. can we also compress the result of our algorithm with gzip or similar? (Edit: am I asking the same thing as Dennis?)

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix yes, that's the same question as Dennis, and its still allowed :)

Comment: So we are allowed to depend on the fact that A is first and B is second? Basically, can we use the order of the input to our advantage?

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix absolutely.

Comment: umm.. [file not found](https://github.com/turbo/Halite/raw/60024b5cf63d96aac7762f4ba0ecad5d8ef54c67/README.md) Edit: [13th line, first entry](https://gist.github.com/nathanmerrill/125a6e2ae7d9ded3531fedff036cf74b#file-commits-txt-L13)

Comment: Bah, link rot already?  There are now *49* test cases.

Comment: More link rot: numbering test case pairs by 1-base line index; both pairs of test cases 3, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21 are all 404.  Outside of these, I managed to retrieve every other case.

Comment: I'm closing this question because it is largely unanswered and many of the old links I was using as test cases no longer work.  Feel free to update the question and reopen if you wish.

Comment: I think it is still an interesting question but maybe you could update the links to have a static .tar file on github?

Comment: @Seth I agree, but getting all of the links was quite a bit of work, and I'm not really motivated to do it again.  If you are up for the task, be my guest :)

Comment: Done.  The GIST is https://gist.github.com/sethhillbrand/64066935e3f8c0fac75d75edd43c9ef8

The second file is a uuencoded archive of the 40 remaining pairs of test cases.

Comment: @Dennis: Question doesn't seem unclear.  Could you add a comment to specify what your concern is?

Comment: @Seth sorry for the late reply.  The question was closed by my request.  I've tried opening up your `commits.uu` file, and I'm struggling to get it decoded, which is why I haven't reopened the question.

Comment: Got it.  To simplify, I've updated the gist with the files base64 encoded as this seems to be more standard than uudecode these days.  To extract the files, save the gist as commits.tar.xz.64 and execute `base64 -d commits.tar.xz.64|tar -xvJ`

Answer (score 0):

Is my answer valid?

```
set f [open commits.txt]
while {![eof $f]} {scan [gets $f] %s\ %s a b; puts [string compare $a $b]}
close $f
```

testable on: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNmd4QkxvQUFsTnM

Comment: You need to provide multiple programs (both a `diff` equivalent and a `patch` equivalent). If `string compare` diffs strings, it violates the "no builtins" rule. If it only compares strings (like the name suggests), it doesn't leave enough information to recreate a patch.

Comment: @ais523: builtins I understood it as command line commands. I know that `string compare` does not generate info to create a page, but there is no place in the question asking for it.

Comment: From the question, "2. Input A and C, and output B". This is something that your submitted program can't do, and that in fact no program could do (as it doesn't have enough information).

Comment: @ais523: OK I misunderstood.

Comment: @ais523: I don't think your statement is correct "in fact no program could do".  If C is the diff between A and B, then given C and A, B is calculable.  Maybe I missed your exact point

Comment: @Seth: Sergiol's definition of a "diff" destroys data, so it isn't reversible (and isn't really a diff). That was the point I was trying to get at. The "write a program to reverse the diffing operation" part of the question is a nice objective way to ensure that the diff actually is a diff.

Comment: @ais523: That makes sense.  Agreed.